# Why the payment.customer_id is wrong?

Tags: postgresql

```
SELECT customer.customer_id, first_name, last_name, SUM(amount)
FROM customer
INNER JOIN payment
ON customer.customer_id = payment.customer_id
GROUP BY customer.customer_id
ORDER BY customer.customer_id;
```

This query is giving correct answer but when I am writing

```
SELECT payment.customer_id, first_name, last_name, SUM(amount)
FROM customer
INNER JOIN payment
ON customer.customer_id = payment.customer_id
GROUP BY payment.customer_id
ORDER BY customer.customer_id;
```

It's showing up errors.

Comment: Add the error message, please

Comment: ERROR:  column "customer.first_name" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
LINE 1: SELECT payment.customer_id, first_name, last_name, SUM(amoun...
                                    ^
SQL state: 42803
Character: 29

Comment: Why can't I GROUP BY by any element from payment table

Answer (score 0):

I guess that `customer_id` is a primary key of `customer` table and therefore you can select other columns from `customer` table when grouping by it - see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html#SQL-GROUPBY:

> When GROUP BY is present, or any aggregate functions are present, it
>   is not valid for the SELECT list expressions to refer to ungrouped
>   columns except within aggregate functions or when the ungrouped column
>   is functionally dependent on the grouped columns, since there would
>   otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped
>   column. A functional dependency exists if the grouped columns (or a
>   subset thereof) are the primary key of the table containing the
>   ungrouped column.